# Boundary condition is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the domain

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am attempting to solve a PDE as prescribed in a paper I am reading; however, Mathematica doesn't seem to be happy with the way I am posing the problem.

Im my case, r(t,100) is an approximation of r(t,inf).

```
d = 27;
k = 10;
s = 1;

sol = NDSolve[
  {D[u[t, r], t] == d*(1/r^2) D[r^2*D[u[t, r], r], r], 
   u[0, r] == 1, 
   Derivative[0, 1][u][t, s] == (k/d)*u[t, s], u[t, 100] == 1}, 

  u, {t, 0, 10}, {r, 0, 100}]
```

I am receiving an error stating that my boundary condition u(t,100)==1 is not specified on a single edge of the boundary of the computational domain.  The answer is probably very simple, however I am just not seeing it.

Answer (score 3):

That means the boundary conditions defined should fit the the range of `t` and `r` in `NDSolve` command. 
You have 4 values: `{t,0,10}` and `{r,0,100}`, so you have to define the conditions at these 4 values. Here you define at `r = s = 1` but you run `r` from 0 to 100. You need to define the boundary condition at `r = 0` and at `r = 100`. But I don't know which boundary condition you need for `r = 0`, so I just run the `NDSolve` from `s` to `100` where at theses limits, the boundary conditions are well defined.

So this is the correct way to define the boundary conditions:

```
d = 27;
k = 10;
s = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, r], t] == d*(1/r^2) D[r^2*D[u[t, r], r], r],
   u[0, r] == 1,
   Derivative[0, 1][u][t, s] == (k/d)*u[t, s],
   u[t, 100] == 1},
  u,
  {t, 0, 10}, {r, s, 100}]


Plot[u[10, r] /. sol, {r, s, 100}]
```

[image]